# NSInternalInconsistencyException: Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.6

2013-02-10 20:35:31.736 spellgate[8771:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'EndRoundVC''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x212f022 0x1aa7cd6 0x20d7a48 0x20d79b9 0xe2b638 0xcd11fc 0xcd1779 0xcd199b 0xc30401 0xc30a46 0x835e 0x2130e99 0xc0d14e 0xc0d0e6 0xcb3ade 0xcb3fa7 0xcb3266 0xc323c0 0xc325e6 0xc18dc4 0xc0c634 0x22c2ef5 0x2103195 0x2067ff2 0x20668da 0x2065d84 0x2065c9b 0x22c17d8 0x22c188a 0xc0a626 0x2dad 0x2cd5)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

I have verified that the target object is the app and that the .xib is a part of the build. I believe it is related to the way I am calling the .xib:

```
EndRoundVC *roundEnded = [[EndRoundVC alloc] init];
[self.view.window setRootViewController:roundEnded];
```

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I've seen this error when the NIB was referencing a class other than the VC loading it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create your VC like this:

```
EndRoundVC *roundEnded = [[EndRoundVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"EndRoundVC" bundle:nil];
```

Hopefully this works.

Comment: I tried that but it just creates a loop and never actually switches the view

Comment: Also why are you doing self.view.window and NOT self.window? If you are doing this in AppDelegate then you must use self.window.